# Case statement on a join in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to use a `CASE` statement inside a `WHERE` clause for joining 2 tables. I want to evaluate `POSITION_NBR2`, if it is blank (null) then I want to join `A.POSITION_NBR2 = B.POSITION_NBR` Else I want to join `A.POSITION_NBR = B.POSITION_NBR` , however I am getting syntax errors while trying to run the following:

```
UPDATE #WORKTABLE
SET SLT_MEMBER = B.NAME
FROM PS_GHS_FTE_SLT A,
     PS_EMPLOYEES B,
     #WORKTABLE C
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN A.POSITION_NBR2  <> '' THEN A.POSITION_NBR2 = B.POSITION_NBR
       ELSE A.POSITION_NBR = B.POSITION_NBR
       END
  AND A.DEPTID COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = C.DEPTID COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
  AND B.EMPL_STATUS = 'A'
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  You should specify the error that you are getting as well.

Comment: Just to clarify when Position_Nbr2 is NULL you want to use it in your join? That seems wrong.

Comment: When `POSITION_NBR2' is NOT null (blank) then I want to use the join A.POSITION_NBR2 = B.POSITION_NBR  Else use the join A.POSITION_NBR = B.POSITION_NBR. The POSITION_NBR field exists on both Table A and B. The only differerence is if A.POSITION_NBR2 is not null, then I want to join that field to B.POSITION_TBL

Comment: Also you are saying `NULL` but in your code you are testing for an empty string `''` Which is it? Those are two very different things. If it's actually a NULL then you can join with a `COALESCE()` like `FROM PS_GHS_FTE_SLT A INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON COALESCE(A.POSITION_NBR2, A.POSITION_NBR) = B.POSITION_NBR`

Comment: '' (empty string) is what I want to evaluate for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper `JOIN` syntax and reasonable table aliases:

```
UPDATE WT
    SET SLT_MEMBER = E.NAME
FROM PS_GHS_FTE_SLT GFS JOIN
     PS_EMPLOYEES E
     ON E.POSITION_NBR = (CASE WHEN GFS.POSITION_NBR2 <> '' THEN GFS.POSITION_NBR2 ELSE GFS.POSITION_NBR
                          END) JOIN
     #WORKTABLE WT
     ON GFS.DEPTID COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = WT.DEPTID COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
WHERE E.EMPL_STATUS = 'A';
```

I'm generally not a fan of using `CASE` for `ON` and `WHERE` clauses.  In this case, though, it is only selectively choosing one column, so it doesn't bother me so much.